# Set MUI icon color correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-admin

I have a functional component which should set some default values for `react-admin`'s `BooleanField` like this:

```js
    import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear'
    import DoneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Done'
    import get from 'lodash/get'
    import { BooleanField, BooleanFieldProps, useRecordContext } from 'react-admin'
    import { SvgIcon } from '@mui/material'
    
    const EventBooleanField = (props: BooleanFieldProps): JSX.Element => {
      const { source, label, valueLabelTrue } = props
      const record = useRecordContext(props)
    
      const TrueIcon: typeof SvgIcon = () => {
        return <DoneIcon color="success" />
      }
      TrueIcon.muiName = 'TrueIcon'
    
      const FalseIcon: typeof SvgIcon = () => {
        return <ClearIcon color="disabled" />
      }
      FalseIcon.muiName = 'FalseIcon'
    
      return (
        <BooleanField
          sortable={false}
          source={source}
          valueLabelTrue={`${label}: ${get(record, valueLabelTrue)}`}
          valueLabelFalse={`${label}: -`}
          TrueIcon={TrueIcon}
          FalseIcon={FalseIcon}
        />
      )
    }
    export default EventBooleanField
```

It basically works, but the tooltip functionality seems broken as it does not display and in the console I can see:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Tooltip2)`
```

It seems that it does not like that I set the `color` prop of the mui icon in a functional component. How can I make this work?

Comment: Where is the tooltip coming from?

Comment: The tooltip is part of the `BooleanField` of `react-admin` and is actually just the `Tooltip` component of MUI.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use React.forwardRef to wrap your icons. Since that tooltip passes a ref to them. And you should spread props

```
const FalseIcon = React.forwardRef<any, any>((props, ref) => {
   return <ClearIcon ref={ref} {...props} color="disabled" />
})
```

And something important: Never ever create a component inside another component, unless you do not keep its reference (with something like `useCallback`)!!!
Move your `TrueIcon` and `FalseIcon` outside of the `EventBooleanField`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will lead to a type error when used in `BooleanField` of `react-admin` for the `FalseIcon` field: `Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<any, string | number | symbol> & RefAttributes<any>>' is not assignable to type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }'`

Comment: Now sure about the type, react-admin restricts those icon components types. You can bypass it like this:  const FalseIcon = ... as unknown as SvgIconComponent (imported from '@mui/icons-material')

Comment: I had to add the props as well like this: `const FalseIcon = forwardRef<any, any>((props, ref) => {
  return <ClearIcon color="disabled" ref={ref} {...props} />
}) as unknown as SvgIconComponent` 
But to be honest it's quite ugly and nothing that should count as a solution.

Comment: using forwardRef and spreading props fixes your problem. About  the ugly part, react-admin restrictions..., most of the time you have to do those ugly things if you want to use it.